# GIT add or commit?

Tags: git, commit

We are working on a project as a team.

I have just cloned the project from github

I have the project on my computer - `wamp`.

I added a new file and I want to update my `local`.

I have used the `git add  xxx.php` but the newly added file is still not visible to `wamp/apache`.

Do I need to commit to have this new file visible in `wamp`?

Does using commit update the main project in `github` or just my clone?

Comment: with what technique do the files get deployed in wamp?

Comment: This depends on where wamp looks for files. Git add adds any untracked files to your repository. Git commit will then update your local version (you will need to write a change log). If you then wanted to update the remote repository you will then have to use git push and everyone else will have to use git pull to get the changes you have made into their local copy. If wamp looks at your local copy you shouldn't have to use any git commands to view the files but if it looks at the remote server you will have to commit then push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to do both `git add` and `git commit` to actually store changes in the repository. If you want to share those changes with others in another repository, you will also have to *push* your changes.

Please read about the basics of Git in the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics). Or check out some other tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Commit updates only your local repository. Push then propagates these updates from your local repository to the remote repository (github).